# SOME WCF calls return site home page

Tags: asp.net, wcf, iis-6

On an IIS6 server, some WCF services return the home page instead of a useful result.

In IIS, wildcard, axd and svc are all registered to aspnet_isapi.dll.

The site user has full permissions to everything.

Interestingly enough, when viewing the site through a local Cassini install, everything works fine.

Suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

2 possible suggestions:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/wenlong/archive/2006/09/10/748294.aspx may help.

Also, Under IIS Manager, open Web Service Extension and make sure that ASP.NET v2.0.5.0727 is set to Allowed. (or the ASP.NET v4.... one if thats what you're using)

In fact, [WCF not running under IIS 6.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/451701/wcf-not-running-under-iis-6-0) has some helpful hints.