# Enable WCF Service to use with JSON

Tags: c#, .net, json, wcf

I have created a wcf service. That is working fine when i am using simply in .net by adding as a webservice. But i want to make it able to use for iPhone app as JSON call. For testing i have used it in .net with JSON but its not working.

i know this kind of question is asked before, i have looked in for this cant find solution for me.

my configuration:

```
<system.serviceModel>
<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="servicebehavior">
      <serviceMetadata httpsGetEnabled="true" />
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
  <endpointBehaviors>
    <behavior name="endpointBehavior">
      <enableWebScript />
      <webHttp defaultBodyStyle="Wrapped" defaultOutgoingResponseFormat="Json" />
    </behavior>
  </endpointBehaviors>

</behaviors>
<serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" />
<services>
  <service name="MyService" behaviorConfiguration="servicebehavior">
    <endpoint address=""
              behaviorConfiguration="endpointBehavior"
              binding="webHttpBinding"
              contract="IMyService" />
  </service>
</services>
```

interface code:

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IGolfPyramidService
{



    [WebInvoke(UriTemplate = "/Test", Method = "POST", ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.WrappedRequest)]
    [OperationContract]
    string Test();

}
```

Myservice.cs code:

```
[AspNetCompatibilityRequirements(RequirementsMode = AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsMode.Allowed)]
public class MyService : IMyService
{        
    public string Test()
    {
        return "success";
    }
}
```

i want to make it possible to call the method using url format like :
http://example.com/MyService.svc/test

Comment: Why are you using WebInvoke On your interface and not WebGet?

Comment: Thanks for reply.. for my case i want to get reply in JSON and i was getting problems with WebGet Method. The WebInvoke method worked for me.

Comment: If you call the webservice from the browser you are using GET, not POST.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

if you are beginner then this will guide you create json and xml enabled web service which can be consumed by IOS and android.
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/105273/Create-RESTful-WCF-Service-API-Step-By-Step-Guide

Comment: i still have a small problem... i am geting the output data but not in JSON format. I have specified  ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json as described in article but it gives result in simple format not in JSON

Answer (score 7):

Why you use a post method to get a simple string value ? Try this example which should normally work.

Configuration

```
  <system.serviceModel>
<services>
  <service behaviorConfiguration="RestServiceBehavior" name="WcfService1.MyService">
    <endpoint address="" behaviorConfiguration="web" binding="webHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="webHttpBindingWithJSONP" contract="WcfService1.IMyService" />
  </service>
</services>
<bindings>
  <webHttpBinding>
    <binding name="webHttpBindingWithJSONP" />
  </webHttpBinding>
</bindings>
<behaviors>
  <endpointBehaviors>
    <behavior name="web">
      <webHttp />
    </behavior>
  </endpointBehaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="RestServiceBehavior">
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>
<serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
```

IMyService.cs

```
namespace WcfService1
{
[ServiceContract]
public interface IMyService
{
    [WebGet(UriTemplate = "Test",
        ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json
    )]
    [OperationContract]
    string Test();
}
}
```

MyService.svc.cs

```
namespace WcfService1
{
[AspNetCompatibilityRequirements(RequirementsMode = AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsMode.Allowed)]
public class MyService : IMyService
{
    public string Test()
    {
        return "Test";
    }
}
}
```

Comment: though previous answer worked for.. 
i have tried your solution also that is with WEBGET and it worked for me also..
The problem in my code seems to be in 2 places
1. i have set httpsgetenabled=true now i have changed it to httpgetenabled=true 
2. i had just placed references in web config file without namespace

i think these both were the problems